# Excel VBA: How can function return string with a variety of colored characters?

Tags: string, vba, colors

I have the code below that's supposed to generate a string like 
`"XXXXX|XXXXX|XXXXX|XXXXX|XXXXX|XXXXX"`.
This represents 5 weekdays each across 6 weeks for scheduling I'm building.
I also want the first few X's to be black, the remainder red.  For example, we might be part way through the second week, and I'll want the first 7 X's to be black, and all remainder red.

My code generates this string just fine.  However, I can't figure out to make the color happen.  I couldn't figure out how to color my actual string that gets returned from the function.  So I tried adding a self cell reference (the TargetCell parameter), so that as soon as I build the string, I could color the result.

In my spreadsheet cell D3 I have the formula
`=BuildColorString(A3, A4, A5, C2, C3, D3, B41:B45)`
Don't worry much about the first 5 parameters or the last parameter.  Focus on the 6th parameter, that is the self reference to D3.

Anyway, if I make that 5th parameter some totally different cell, the text in that cell gets colored correctly.  However, if I try to color the result of what I'm generating, it doesn't work.

I realize I have a chicken-and-egg problem here.  I can't figure out how to get past it.

I also tried splitting the string generation from the coloring.  I put the coloring behind a button I push.  It doesn't work.  I can't seem to color the result of the function's string build.

Below is my code:

```
Function BuildColorString(BeginDate As Date, EndDate As Date, Holidays As Integer, AsOfDate As Date, HolidaysPassed As Integer, TargetCell As Range, rColors As Range)
Dim iDayCount As Integer
Dim iPosition As Integer
Dim iColor As Integer
Dim WIPDate As Date
Dim iWeekDay As Integer

' BUILD STRING
BuildColorString = ""
WIPDate = BeginDate
While WIPDate <= EndDate
    iWeekDay = Weekday(WIPDate)
    If (iWeekDay = 1) Then
        'Sunday
    Else
        If (iWeekDay = 7) Then
            'Saturday
            If (WIPDate <> BeginDate) Then
                BuildColorString = BuildColorString & "|"
            End If
        Else
            'Weekday
            BuildColorString = BuildColorString & "X"
        End If
    End If
    WIPDate = WIPDate + 1
Wend

' COLORIZE STRING
WIPDate = BeginDate
iDayCount = 1
iPosition = 1
While WIPDate <= EndDate
    iWeekDay = Weekday(WIPDate)
    If (iWeekDay = 1) Then
        'Sunday
    Else
        If (iWeekDay = 7) Then
            'Saturday
            If (WIPDate <> BeginDate) Then
                iPosition = iPosition + 1
            End If
        Else
            'Weekday
            If (iPosition <= 5) Then
                ' BLACK, Prior Completed
                iColor = rColors(1, 1).Characters(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex
            Else
                ' GREEN, Recent Completed
                iColor = rColors(3, 1).Characters(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex
            End If

            TargetCell(1, 1).Characters(iPosition, 1).Font.ColorIndex = iColor

            ' BuildColorString.Characters(iPosition, 1).Font.ColorIndex = vbRed 'rColor.Font.ColorIndex
            iDayCount = iDayCount + 1
            iPosition = iPosition + 1
        End If
    End If
    WIPDate = WIPDate + 1
Wend


End Function
```

Comment: VBA functions used as a UDF from a worksheet cell typically can only return a value to the calling cell(s): they cannot modify the sheet directly (including changing formatting).  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787